# how to replace everything except "- or +" & digit in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const lat = "-3340Abcs"
const newLat = lat.replace(/\D/g,"") // getting 3340

//expecting -3340
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `/[^-+\d]/g`

```js
const lat = "-3340Abcs";
const newLat = lat.replace(/[^-+\d]/g, "");

console.log(newLat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your expected result is a number. You can use look behind if you want to also remove `+` and `-` in the middle of the string:

```js
const lat = "-3340Ab+c-s"
const newLat = lat.replace(/(?<=^)[^+-\d]|(?<!^)\D/g,"");

console.log(newLat);
```

Comment: const lat = "-33.40Ab+c-s"
    const newLat = lat.replace(/(?<=^)[^+-\d]|(?<!^)\D/g,""); // getting -3340

    //expecting -33.40

Comment: @AliRazaShaheb That's a different question. You should ask a new one. In this question you asked to replace every character other than digits, `+` and `-`. That's answered by both answers. Now you want to keep another character. You should also specify the expected result. Do you want to keep all `.` or only the first? What's the expected result of `a.b.c-123.23e.f.g` or `-a-123.23`?

Comment: Hi.... Thank you  for your kind reply.... I found out later that data I am getting from api is very troublesome. It will be appreciate if your goodself help me solve my question. I want to keep the first "." rest will be replace with nothing.

Comment: @AliRazaShaheb As I said you already asked a specific question and got two valid answers. You shouldn't change this question because then the answers wouldn't make any sense. Ask a new question with better specification of your problem. You should also consider cases like `a.b-2.4`. Do you really expect `.24` or `.-24` as result? That's your current description (keep the first `.` and remove all other).